# Update NTEXT column in SQL Server CE in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to update definition but facing an exception

> SQL Server does not provide comparison of NETXT, XML, Image etc

don't know how to handle it.

My table structure looks like this:

```
[Table]
public class Dictionary
{
    private string _definition;

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public string Word
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Column(CanBeNull = false, Storage="_definition", DbType="NTEXT")]
    public string Definition
    {
        get { return this._definition; }
        set { this._definition = value; }
    }
}
```

Here is my update code

```
using (DictionaryDataContext d8db = new DictionaryDataContext(strConnectionString))
{
            IQueryable<Dictionary> DicQuery = from word in d8db.tb_Dictionary where word.Word == w.Word select word;
            Dictionary wordShow = DicQuery.FirstOrDefault();
            wordShow.Definition = "some string";
            d8db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a rowversion column to your Dictionary class:

```
 [Column(IsVersion = true)]
 private Binary _version;
```

Comment: But i want to use NTEXT .. can any one help?